# Angular get error during to use Material Grid List

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to show a list of items as a grid
I try to use the material grid to arrange my item list, like this:

```
 <mat-grid-list cols="3" class="border-list specials-list">
   <a *ngFor="let item of specials; index as i" [href]="item?.link">
    <img [src]="item.src" [alt]="item.title" />
    <span class="image-title">{{ item.title }}</span>
  </a>
</mat-grid-list>
```

ts:

```
       @Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    NgbModule,
    MatDialogModule,
  ],
  standalone: true,
})
        export class HomeComponent {
          constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}
    
          specials: AppListModel[] = [
           {
          title: 'x',
          src: '../../assets/images/logos/irancell.png',
          link: 'https://cdn-ngmy.irancell.ir/app/MyIrancell.apk',
        },
        {
          title: 'y',
          src: '../../assets/images/logos/Okala.jpg',
          link: 'https://trc.metrix.ir/dueaid/?Token=%7BToken%7D',
        }
      ];
    }
```

but whene serve the project got an error:

[image]